# ms-word url scheme does not work from Chrome browser on Mac OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, google-chrome, ms-word, url-scheme

We have been facing an issue with Chrome browser to open a word file document from Apache2 WebDav server. 
(no error output from console.)

I found a related article (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/INSmAWDLq7I;context-place=forum/chrome), but this seems not to be solved yet.

I've tried multiple approaches like

`<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|:https://example.com"> Open from Word </a>`

or from javascript

`window.location.href = "ms-word:ofe|u|:https://example.com"`

Apache2 runs on CentOS server, and I am an administrator of the server.

The both approaches above work fine with Safari browser.

Answer (score 2):

solved this myself.....it was just a problem on my end,  I couldn't get this working because I was giving a url like

`ms-word:ofe|u|'your-webdav-url`.

if you simply escape letters

`ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7C'your-webdav-url'`